# How to test that the DB was NOT queried

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix app, I have a function which fetches some data from the DB and then caches it in an `Agent`. How can I write a test to ensure only the first time a value is requested the DB is actually queried?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the simplest way to test this is to:

1. Call the agent and store the value
2. Modify the value on the database
3. Call the agent again and expect the first value

```
:ok = DB.insert("old_value")
assert {:ok, "old_value"} = YourCache.get_value()
:ok = DB.insert("new_value")
assert {:ok, "old_value"} = YourCache.get_value()
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this would be to mock the DB instance with e.g. [`Mox`](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html) to use an [explicit contact](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) for the DB queries.

---

If you are using `Ecto`, it does it itself; check the `config/test.exs` file to see that it uses `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox` in tests. Copy the whole [`sandbox.ex`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.6/lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex) file to your test suite, modify [`Connection.handle_execute/4`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.6/lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex#L335) to perform something like `IO.puts` to a console or like. Change your `test.exs` config to use this pool. Then check that the first time it was printed, and the second time it was not.

That might look like an overkill here, but in the long run, this approach would pay back (I’d say sooner rather than later.)